# How to color specific portions of this graph?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have a data.frame named df.ordered that looks like:

```
              gvs order           labels color
1  -2.3321916     1           Adygei     1
13 -0.8519079     2           Basque     1
46 -0.9298674     3           French     1
47 -2.8859587     4          Italian     1
2  -1.4996229     5         Orcadian     1
9  -1.5597359     6          Russian     1
48 -1.4494841     7        Sardinian     1
14 -2.4279528     8           Tuscan     1
15 -3.1717421     9          Bedouin     2
22 -0.5058627    10            Druze     2
39 -2.6491331    11         Mozabite     2
23 -0.7819299    12      Palestinian     2
24 -1.4095947    13          Balochi     3
10 -1.2534511    14           Brahui     3
3   1.7958170    15          Burusho     3
25  2.2810477    16           Hazara     3
16 -0.9258497    17           Kalash     3
26 -0.9007551    18          Makrani     3
4   2.5543214    19           Pathan     3
27  2.6614486    20           Sindhi     3
17 -1.2207974    21           Uygurf     3
40  2.3706977    22        Cambodian     4
28 -0.9441980    23              Dai     4
18 -1.0325107    24             Daur     4
49 -0.7381369    25              Han     4
41 -2.7590587    26           Hezhen     4
50 -0.5644325    27         Japanese     4
44 -0.8449225    28             Lahu     4
29 -0.7237586    29             Miao     4
30 -0.9452944    30          Mongola     4
11 -0.1625003    31             Naxi     4
31 -1.2035258    32           Oroqen     4
5  -2.7758460    33              She     4
32 -0.7703779    34               Tu     4
12 -1.0265275    35            Tujia     4
45 -1.1163019    36             Xibo     4
19 -3.2102686    37            Yakut     4
42 -0.9614190    38               Yi     4
6  -1.9659984    39        Colombian     5
51 -0.9195156    40        Karitiana     5
7   2.1239768    41             Maya     5
33 -3.0895998    42             Pima     5
20 -0.9377928    43            Surui     5
43 -1.6961014    44       Melanesian     6
34 -0.7037952    45           Papuan     6
35 -1.9311354    46       BantuKenya     7
8  -1.8515908    47 BantuSouthAfrica     7
21 -1.7657017    48       BiakaPygmy     7
36 -0.5423822    49         Mandenka     7
37 -1.6244801    50       MbutiPygmy     7
38 -0.9049735    51              San     7
52  2.0949378    52           Yoruba     7
```

I have made a graph using the following code from Snoram:

```
jpeg("test3.jpg", 700,700)
plot(df.ordered$gvs, pch = 19,)
axis(1, at=1:52, labels=df.ordered$labels, las=2)
dev.off()
```

The graph looks like

[image]

I would now like to color code the graph based on the color column. For each point plotted on the graph, I would like the dot to be colored the same color as points in the same color group as it from the color column. For example, I would like the first 8 points to be blue (color column = 1), the next 4 points to be orange (color column = 2). Does anyone know how this would be done? An example of what I want my dot colors/axis colors to look like is in Figure 5 in this paper http://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1004412. Also does anyone know how to get rid of starting my x-axis at 0 weirdly like it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# This will colour based on the number, but they may not be the colours you want.
plot(df.ordered$gvs, pch = 19, col = colors()[df.ordered$color], xaxt="n")
```

If you have specific colours in mind for each number, change the numbers to the character string of the colour.

For instance:

```
df.ordered$color <- as.factor(df.ordered$color)
levels(df.ordered$color) <- c("red","orange" ... etc)
## Not sure if you need the as.character here, but might as well for good measure
plot(df.ordered$gvs, pch = 19, col = as.character(df.ordered$color), xaxt="n")
```

`xaxt = "n"` is the code you were looking for to fix you x axis. Because you are declaring the axis after the plot you need to eliminate the x axis plotted in `plot()`.

An additional consideration. `axis()` plots a standard axis, since you are suppressing the axis anyway might I recommend an angled x axis:

```
## Srt will turn your labels by the number of degrees declared, making them easier for you to read.
## Be sure to set your y to a position below the bottom of your y-axis, may take some toying with.

text( x = 1:52, y = -4, labels=df.ordered$labels, srt=45, xpd=T )
```

Comment: This works great! Is there a way to also get the labels the same color as their dots? Currently the graph looks like: http://imgur.com/a/0pd2e

Comment: `axis()` also has a `col` argument, just fill that in the same way. The same goes for `text()`

Comment: I tried the `axis()` with `col` argument and it didn't work. I'd try the `text()` option but I don't like how I lose the tick marks with it =/

Comment: You can make the ticks marks using `axis` and just have no labels, there are other ways too, I personally use `text` to place my tick marks.

Comment: Got it, the `axis(col=...)` colours the tick while `text(col=...)` colours the text. Consider: `axis(side = 1,at=1:52,col="red",labels="")
text(0,-4,labels = df.ordered$labels,col="red",xpd=T)`

Comment: I'm confused, which one should I be using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117857/discussion-between-badger-and-evan).